# create a table of duplicated rows of another table using the select statement

Tags: sql, select, teradata

I have a table with one column containing different integers. 
For each integer in the table I would like to duplicate it as the number of digits -
For example:

> 12345 (5 digits): 
>   1. 12345 
>   2. 12345 
>   3. 12345 
>   4. 12345 
>   5. 12345

I thought doing it using `with recursion t (...) as ()` but I didn't manage, since I don't really understand how it works and what is happening "behind the scenes. 
I don't want to use `insert` because I want it to be scalable and automatic for as many integers as needed in a table. 
Any thoughts and an explanation would be great.

Comment: In your example you want to create 5 rows with the same value 12345? Do you need the 1./2./3./4./5. as a new column, too? Or was this just a kind of row number?

Comment: I don't really need the new column, just the number itself.

Comment: Just one more question: Why do you need that? I can't imaging any real world scenario...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to join to a table with numbers from 1 to n in it.

```
SELECT n, x
FROM yourtable
JOIN
 (
   SELECT day_of_calendar AS n 
   FROM sys_calendar.CALENDAR
   WHERE n BETWEEN 1 AND 12 -- maximum number of digits 
 ) AS dt
ON n <= CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(ABS(x)))
```

In my example I abused TD's builtin calendar, but that's not a good choice, as the optimizer doesn't know how many rows will be returned and as the plan must be a Product Join it might decide to do something stupid. So better use a number table...

Answer (score 0):

Create a numbers table that will contain the integers from 1 to the maximum number of digits that the numbers in your table will have (I went with 6):

```
create table numbers(num int)
insert numbers
select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6
```

You already have your table (but here's what I was using to test):

```
create table your_table(num int)
insert your_table
select 12345 union select 678
```

Here's the query to get your results:

```
select ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b.num order by b.num) row_num, b.num, LEN(cast(b.num as char)) num_digits
into #temp
from your_table b
cross join numbers n    

select t.num
from #temp t
where t.row_num <= t.num_digits
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice way to perform this action. Here goes:

```
with recursive t (num,num_as_char,char_n)
as 
(
    select   num
            ,cast (num as varchar (100)) as num_as_char
            ,substr (num_as_char,1,1)   

    from    numbers

    union all 

    select   num
            ,substr (t.num_as_char,2) as num_as_char2
            ,substr (num_as_char2,1,1)  

    from    t       

    where   char_length (num_as_char2) > 0
)

select  *
from    t
order by num,char_length (num_as_char) desc
```